# Retrieve data from databse using where in JSP

Tags: jsp, select

can somebody help me?

I have a jsp page. in that i want to get data from the database where username is matched. i tried it. but can't get the output. here is the code. please help me. ALL DATABASE CONNECTIONS ARE OK. THE ERROR IS SHOWN IN "WHERE". IT SAYS INCORRECT SQL SYNTAX

```
<html>
   .....
<body>
 <%
      //table name is "register" have Name and Username filed.
      String uname=request.getParameter("username");
      String sql;
      sql="SELECT * FROM register WHERE Username="+uname+"";
      ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
      while(rs.next())
                    {
      %>          

   NAME: <%=rs.getString(1)%> 
   USERNAME: <%=rs.getString(2)%> 

       <%        
                }
         %> 

   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 sql="SELECT * FROM register WHERE Username= '"+uname+"'";
```

you may also want to consider running the query first in your db console to work out things like this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with the query.

To check this, go to mysql  tool or command prompt whichever you are using

use the same syntax by hotcoding some value such as

SELECT * FROM **databasename.register** WHERE Username="vector" . If it works then

The exception may be because of three other reasons

check

1. database name
2. Table name
3. Field name

Still if it does not work tell me.